# Allow User to Name New File

Tags: python

How do I allow the user to name "copied_holter.ecg" themselves? I provided that name, but I want the user to choose whatever they want.

```
class MyParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
def error(self, message):
    sys.stderr.write('error: %s\n' % message)
    self.print_help()
    sys.exit(2)



parser = MyParser(util_help)
parser.add_argument('filename', help='The full path/to/holter_file that you would like to parse.', action="store")
parser.add_argument('packet_start', help='The offset location of the start packet ID in base 10 decimal', action="store", type = int)
parser.add_argument('packet_end', help='The offset location of the end packet ID in base 10 decimal', action = "store", type = int)
parser.add_argument('new_filename', help='The name of the new file with the copied holter data chosen by user.', action = "store")
args = parser.parse_args()

start = args.packet_start
end = args.packet_end

if start % 5 != 0:
  start = int(5*round(float(start)/5))
if end % 5 != 0:
  end = int(5*round(float(end)/5))

try:
  print("Beginning copying of holter data...")

# Output the specific holter data
output_file = open(new_filename+".ecg", 'w')
```

Comment: This code doesn't tell us anything....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

all you need to do is on the line

```
output_file = open(file_name+".ecg", "w")
```

replace it with

```
output_file = open(args.new_filename, 'w')
```

Answer (score 1):

Parse `file_name` from arg, and then use something like:

```
output_file = open(file_name+".ecg", "w")
```

Comment: this is not pythonic, and not to mention you are assuming every file will end with `.ecg`

Comment: why this is not pythonic?? i thought he want store this file with same postfix as original suffix

Comment: the pythonic way is using `with` because it will open and close the file for you and it's much more readible. Also bad assumption because OP stated he wanted anything for the name.

Comment: @Seekheart I'm sorry? The `with` statement may make things easier, but when you've got a gazillion files and stuff, it's not. This way is no more, nor no less pythonic than with a `with` statement. This is perfectly reasonable. Oddly enough, your own answer doesn't meet your own expectations.